# How to init array of objects in objective-c, similar to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

I am new iOS developer. I started to learn Swift but I want to switch to Objective-C. Below is the code which i'm using in Swift

I have `Player.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct Player {
    var name: String!
    var game: String!
    var rating: Int

    init(name:String?, game:String?, rating:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.game = game
        self.rating = rating
    }
}
```

And I have one class store data Player objects data and this data is using everywhere in project:

```
import Foundation
let playerData = [
    Player(name: "Bill Evan", game: "call of duty", rating: 4),
    Player(name: "Linh Nguyen", game: "Alien vs predator", rating: 3)
]
```

My question is how to do it in Objective-C:

I'm trying to do this in `Player.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Player : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *game;
@property int rating;

-(id)initWithPlayer:(NSString *)name
               game:(NSString*)game
             rating:(int)rat;

@end
```

And in `Player.m`:

```
#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

-(id)initWithPlayer:(NSString *)name game:(NSString *)game rating:(int)rating {
    self.name = name;
    self.game = game;
    self.rating = rating;
    return self;
}
@end
```

How to create array of Player object store many players object?

Comment: Are you asking for the syntax?

Comment: You should use `instancetype` in `init` methods instead of `id`

Answer (score 4):

#### Recommended:

Use a typed array `NSArray<Player *>` so that you don't have to cast the element when accessing it and the compiler warns you if you try to insert non-`Player` objects.

```
NSArray<Player *> *players = @[
    [[Player alloc] initWithPlayer:@"Steven" game:@"Pokémon Go" rating:100],
    [[Player alloc] initWithPlayer:@"Mike" game:@"Pokémon Silver" rating:90]
];

Player *steven = players[0];
steven.rating = steven.rating + 1;
```

---

#### Not recommended:

If you just do

```
NSArray *players = @[ ... see above ... ];
```

You would have to cast like this

```
Player *steven = (Player *)players[0];
```

Also this is more dangerous, since the compiler would also allow you to do this:

```
NSArray *players = @[
    [[Player alloc] initWithPlayer:@"Steven" game:@"Pokémon Go" rating:100],
    @"Just a String, not a Player object"
];
```

This could obviously result in a runtime crash when you're casting the `@"Just a String, ..."` object (`players[1]`) to a Player object.

Comment: oh, thank you so much @MarkHim. i'm just beginer in ios development :)

Comment: One thing, if i create class that store this Array and using it in everywhere in my app. How about this class ?. thank you !

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand correctly, but with #import you can import class headers to other objective c files. Simply Do #import "Players.h" in any other objective-c .h or .m file

Comment: This answer is neat.

Comment: @MarkHim so sorry, my wrong question. :) thank you !

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, you can initialize arrays of objects in Objective-C / Foundation with either one of two methods:

```
// Original, longer way of doing it
NSArray *words = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"list", @"of", @"words"];

// Modern Objective-C shorthand
NSArray *words = @[@"list", @"of", @"words"];
```

A little bit more verbose, but given your object, here's how your Swift code:

```
let playerData = [
    Player(name: "Bill Evan", game: "Call of Duty", rating: 4),
    Player(name: "Linh Nguyen", game: "Alien vs. Predator", rating: 3)
]
```

Would look in Objective-C:

```
NSArray *playerData = @[
    [[Player alloc] initWithPlayer:@"Bill Evan" game:@"Call of Duty" rating:4],
    [[Player alloc] initWithPlayer:@"Linh Nguyen" game:@"Alien vs. Predator" rating:3]
];
```